# How to toggle nested lists using button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a list with nesting and added a button to every parent `<li>` element. The list looks like this:

```js
$("#pr1").append("<button id='bnt-cat13' class='buttons-filter'>expnd1</button>");
$("#pr2").append("<button id='bnt-cat13' class='buttons-filter'>expnd2</button>");
$("#pr3").append("<button id='bnt-cat13' class='buttons-filter'>expnd3</button>");

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $('li > ul').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="categories">
  <li>1</li>
  <li class="parent" id="pr1">2
    <ul class="children">
      <li>2.1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li class="parent" id="pr2">4
    <ul class="children">
      <li>4.1</li>
      <li class="parent" id="pr3">4.2
        <ul class="children">
          <li>4.2.1</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

But this one toggles all list, instead of toggling only separate nested list? 
How to show/hide only separate nested lists clicking the buttons?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the main question - instead of each `li > ul` elements, you have to `toggle` only the `ul` element which is right before a `button`. So you should use [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $(this).prev().toggle();
});
```

```js
$("#pr1").append("<button id='bnt-cat131' class='buttons-filter'>expnd1</button>");
$("#pr2").append("<button id='bnt-cat132' class='buttons-filter'>expnd2</button>");
$("#pr3").append("<button id='bnt-cat133' class='buttons-filter'>expnd3</button>");

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(this).prev().toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="categories">
  <li>1</li>
  <li class="parent" id="pr1">2
    <ul class="children">
      <li>2.1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li class="parent" id="pr2">4
    <ul class="children">
      <li>4.1</li>
      <li class="parent" id="pr3">4.2
        <ul class="children">
          <li>4.2.1</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

---

Your code has another issue that should be fixed - each button has the same `id` attribute (`bnt-cat13`).
[The `id` global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

Comment: In real environment id's are unique. It's a mistake in test example

Answer (score 1):

Change your function into:

```
(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().children('ul').toggle();
  });
});
```